# Edit one file on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment, heroku

All my main tech guys have gone to bed and my site is broken because Google removed jQuery UI 1.8.13. Our commits are not ready for production but I need to just alter my application layout to use 1.8.16 which is the latest.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clone your app into a new directory, make the change and push it back up. Have your tech guys work out getting the repos back in sync on Monday.